# AJAX call unable to send a request Yii2

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii2

I have an AJAX call in my view. The code of it looks like this:

```
<?php 
        $this->registerJs("
        $(document).on('click','.btn-block',function(){
        var id = $(this).parents('.user-tr').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '" . Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . "admin/block-users',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id : id,_csrf : " . Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken() . "},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                },
            });
        })"); 
    ?>
```

I need to send a request to my `actionBlockUsers` function of `AdminController`, which looks like this:

```
public function actionBlockUsers()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            print("success");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I can't send a request. The inspect XHR doesn't show anything either. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you got any JS console errors at all? Does the click event is triggered at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()` into quotes as it would normally contain `==` in the string which will break the script if not inside qutotes, a better way when working with javascript is to use the `yii.js` to get the csrf token and the param name using `yii.getCsrfParam()` and `yii.getCsrfToken()`, rather than hard coding `_csrf`.

Also you should try using [hereDOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) syntax for better readability.

So replace your code with the following in your view

```
$baseUrl=\yii\helpers\Url::base(true);
$js=<<<JS
 $(document).on('click','.btn-block',function(e){
    var id = $(this).parents('.user-tr').attr('id');
    let data={id : id};
    data[yii.getCsrfParam()]=yii.getCsrfToken();

    $.ajax({
        url: '{$baseUrl}/admin/block-users',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            },
        });
    })
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: I get an error `ReferenceError: yii is not defined` in console.

Comment: @GrigoryVolkov that means that the `yii.js` is not loaded, can you see in the view source or add the `AppAsset.php` file, it should have `'yii\web\YiiAsset',` in the `$depends` array

Comment: @GrigoryVolkov glad to help