# How to make a POST request from Ionic to Yii2 using URL

Tags: http, ionic-framework, yii2

What I'm trying to do is that I want to post some data in database using a URL which works totally fine when I put it in the browser, but if I try to do from my ionic app it doesn't work and I get Unknown Error, or the 400 error.

Here is my code :

```
  insertIntoDemande(date_pres : string, client : string, artisant : string
    , adresse : string, metier: string , quartier: string){


      let urlParams =  new URLSearchParams();
      urlParams.append('datepres', date_pres);
      urlParams.append('client', client);
      urlParams.append('cin', artisant);
      urlParams.append('adresse', adresse);
      urlParams.append( 'metier', metier);
      urlParams.append( 'quartier', quartier);         

this.http.post('http://localhost/AlloMealem/backend/web/index.php?r=demandee/createe&'+urlParams.toString(),null).subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log('my data: ', data);
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});

}

}
```

I've already tried to use the PostData in the post method but in didn't work.

Does anyone knows how to make work.

Thanks.

Comment: what didnt worked please elaborate the error you are facing , the information you have added doesnt help much

Comment: It is won't work on the device(app) because you are using localhost, use the live server for work in the app

Comment: This is most likely a CSRF issue if you didnt disable it. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#%24enableCsrfValidation-detail

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam All I'm getting in the console after executing this function in "Bad Request" that all !! but when I copy the URL to the browser the data get inserted.

Comment: @user9088454 I'm executing the app in the browser

Comment: @disembarkedone I've already done, I have already add the get data from database functionalities and it works fine. I have trouble with posting data

Comment: you should use `postData` and add the csrf param along with the other variables when sending the request see this post to learn about csrf param https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57506614/ajax-call-unable-to-send-a-request-yii2/57506942#57506942

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thanks so much you have saved my internship project.

Comment: @YassirAkhmis no problem, you are welcome i would close this question as a duplicate os the post i mentioned in my previous comment if that helped you solve the problem